# I want the string pattern aabbcc to be displayed as 2a2b2c

Tags: java

I have somehow got the output with the help of some browsing. But I couldn't understand the logic behind the code. Is there any simple way to achieve this?

```
public class LetterCount {
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String str = "aabbcccddd";
    int[] counts = new int[(int) Character.MAX_VALUE];
    // If you are certain you will only have ASCII characters, I would use `new int[256]` instead

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char charAt = str.charAt(i);
        counts[(int) charAt]++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++) {
        if (counts[i] > 0)
            //System.out.println("Number of " + (char) i + ": " + counts[i]);
            System.out.print(""+ counts[i] + (char) i + "");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Personally, I would use a `HashMap` to count the characters instead of an `int[]`. You are wasting a lot of space for ASCII characters you don't even use.

Comment: Which bit of the code do you not understand?

Comment: If you want an answer, then someone will place it below. Emailing you personally does not help the overall community here on StackOverflow.

Comment: @AshwinBalajiKuppuraj This technique of using ASCII value as index is very common when working with strings.

Comment: What should the output be for "aabbaa" or "bbaa"?

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 conditions which need to be taken care of:

1. `if (s.charAt(x) != s.charAt(x + 1) && count == 1)` ⇒ print the counter and character;
2. `if (s.charAt(x) == s.charAt(x + 1))` ⇒ increase the counter;
3. `if (s.charAt(x) != s.charAt(x + 1) && count >= 2)` ⇒ reset to counter 1.

```java
{
    int count= 1;
    int x;

    for (x = 0; x < s.length() - 1; x++) {
        if (s.charAt(x) != s.charAt(x + 1) && count == 1) {
            System.out.print(s.charAt(x));
            System.out.print(count);
        }

        else if (s.charAt(x)== s.charAt(x + 1)) {
            count++;
        }

        else if (s.charAt(x) != s.charAt(x + 1) && count >= 2) {
            System.out.print(s.charAt(x));
            System.out.print(count);
            count = 1;
        } 
    }
    System.out.print(s.charAt(x));
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to keep count of the number of times each character is found. An array is referenced by an index. For example, the ASCII code for the lowercase letter a is the integer 97. Thus the count of the number of times the letter a is seen is in `counts[97]`. After every element in the counts array has been set, you print out how many have been found.

Answer (score 1):

The code is really simple.It uses the ASCII value of a character to index into the array that stores the frequency of each character.

The output is simply got by iterating over that array and which character has frequency greater than 1, print it accordingly as you want in the output that is frequency followed by character.

If the input string ***has same characters consecutive*** then the solution can be using **space of O(1)**

For example in your string aabbcc, the same characters are consecutive , so we can take advantage of this fact and count the character frequency and print it at the same time.

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) 
{
 int freq = 1;
 while((i+1)<str.length()&&str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(i+1))
  {++freq;++i}
 System.out.print(freq+str.charAt(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help you understand the basic idea behind how to approach the string compression problem

```
import java.util.*;

public class LetterCount {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //your input string
        String str = "aabbcccddd";
        //split your input into characters
        String chars[] = str.split("");
        //maintain a map to store unique character and its frequency
        Map<String, Integer> compressMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
        //read every letter in input string
        for(String s: chars) {
            //java.lang.String.split(String) method includes empty string in your 
            //split array, so you need to ignore that
            if("".equals(s))
                continue;
            //obtain the previous occurances of the character
            Integer count = compressMap.get(s);
            //if the character was previously encountered, increment its count
            if(count != null)
                compressMap.put(s, ++count);
            else//otherwise store it as first occurance
                compressMap.put(s, 1);
        }
        //Create a StringBuffer object, to append your input
        //StringBuffer is thread safe, so I prefer using it
        //you could use StringBuilder if you don't expect your code to run
        //in a multithreaded environment
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer("");
        //iterate over every entry in map
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : compressMap.entrySet()) {
            //append the results to output
            output.append(entry.getValue()).append(entry.getKey());
        }
        //print the output on console
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution {
  public String toFormat(String input) {
    char inChar[] = input.toCharArray();
    String output = "";
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<input.length();i++) {
      int count = 1;
      while(i+1<input.length() && inChar[i] == inChar[i+1]) {
        count+=1;
        i+=1;
      }
      output+=inChar[i]+String.valueOf(count);
    }
    return output;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Solution sol = new Solution();
    String input = "aaabbbbcc";  
    System.out.println("Formatted String is: " + sol.toFormat(input)); 
  }
}
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.

Answer (score 0):

```
    def encode(Test_string):
        count = 0
        Result = ""
        for i in range(len(Test_string)):
            if (i+1) < len(Test_string) and (Test_string[i] == Test_string[i+1]):
                count += 1
            else:
                Result += str((count+1))+Test_string[i]
                count = 0
        return Result


    print(encode("ABBBBCCCCCCCCAB"))
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the correct count considering the string is not in alphabetical order. Sort the string

```java
public class SquareStrings {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SquareStrings squareStrings = new SquareStrings();

        String str = "abbccddddbd";
        System.out.println(squareStrings.manipulate(str));
    }

    private String manipulate(String str1) {
        //convert to charArray
        char[] charArray = str1.toCharArray();

        Arrays.sort(charArray);

        String str = new String(charArray);

        StringBuilder stbuBuilder = new StringBuilder("");

        int length = str.length();
        String temp = "";
        if (length > 1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                int freq = 1;
                while (((i + 1) < length) && (str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(i + 1))) {
                    ++freq;
                    temp = str.charAt(i) + "" + freq;
                    ++i;
                }
                stbuBuilder.append(temp);
            }
        } else {
            return str + "" + 1;
        }

        return stbuBuilder.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin:

```
fun compressString(input: String): String {
        if (input.isEmpty()){
            return ""
        }
        var result = ""
        var count = 1
        var char1 = input[0]
        for (i in 1 until input.length) {
            val char2 = input[i]
            if (char1 == char2) {
                count++
            } else {
                if (count != 1) {
                    result += "$count$char1"
                    count = 1
                } else {
                    result += "$char1"
                }
                char1 = char2
            }
        }

        result += if (count != 1) {
            "$count$char1"
        } else {
            "$char1"
        }

        return result
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Short and simple 

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
 
    String str="ABCTARCTA";

    Set<Character> set=new HashSet<>();
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
    Map<Character,Integer> map=new HashMap<>();
    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++) {
        Character c=str.charAt(i);
        if(set.add(c)) {
            map.put(c,1);
            sb.append(c);
        } else {
            map.put(c,map.get(c)+1);
            sb.append(map.get(c)).append(c);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

}